i18next language features interfere with NextJS's not-found.jsx, making all paths 200
I'm working on my first proyect with NextJS and the last feature I've added is internationalization with i18next (see docs). Every thing works great except for one thing: NextJs's 404 page, that I've customized using the built-in component not-found.jsx. Apparently, /[locale] interfere with default app routing making all paths available (200 ok). How can I fix it? I've checked every documentation I was able to find so if you know a solution it would be very helpful.




Tried to navigate to mysite.com/inexistingroute and got 200 OK and my homepage rendered
Same happens in the /en version

That has nothing to do with i18next. It's 100% next.js bug. See https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/51021 and https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/62228

Not the same problem! In my case, not only I see 200, the /inexistentroute actually renders my homepage instead of the 404 page

In your [locale]/layout.tsx do if (!locales.include(locale)) notFound()

Could you add more context to your answer? I dont get how to implement that code

You need to validate the path in [locale]/layout.tsx
const locales = ["en", "fr", "ar"];

export default function RootLayout({ params }) {
  if (!locales.includes(params.locale)) notFound();

  // ...
}

This way, if you visited a non-existed page for example /does-not-exist it will render not-found.tsx
